# Use SFINAE to check if types can be bound to template template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, metaprogramming

Is it possible to test if some types can bind to a template template parameter via SFINAE?

I think what I try to do is best explained with the following example code:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename... T> using void_t = void;

template<typename T> struct TemporaryBindObject
{
    using type = TemporaryBindObject<T>;
};

template<template<typename...> class Dest> struct TestValidBind
{
    template<typename... Ts> struct toTypesOf
    {
        using type = std::false_type;
    };
    template<template<typename...> class Src, typename... Ts> struct toTypesOf<Src<Ts...>, void_t<Dest<Ts...,float>>>
    {
        using type = std::true_type;
    };
};

template<typename T> struct OneParamStruct{};
template<typename T1, typename T2> struct TwoParamStruct{};

int main()
{
    using tmp = TemporaryBindObject<int>;

    std::cout << "Can bind to TwoParamStruct: " << TestValidBind<TwoParamStruct>::toTypesOf<tmp>::type::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Can bind to OneParamStruct: " << TestValidBind<OneParamStruct>::toTypesOf<tmp>::type::value << std::endl;
}
```

First I make a temporary type `tmp` from which I want to take the template parameter `int` to bind it to another class template.
With the `TestValidBind<template template type>::toTypesOf<typename>` I want to test if it is possible to bind the parameter of the given type to the `template template parameter` **and** and append an additional type (`float` in the example).

What I want is that `TestValidBind<TwoParamStruct>::toTypesOf<tmp>::type` is `true_type` while `TestValidBind<OneParamStruct>::toTypesOf<tmp>::type` is `false_type`.

---

The code example as it is does not compile with `g++ -std=c++11` (5.3.1) with the following error:

> ../test_SFINAE_with_template_binding.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
>   ../test_SFINAE_with_template_binding.cc:34:96: error:
>   ‘TestValidBind<OneParamStruct>::toTypesOf<TemporaryBindObject<int>
>   >::type’ has not been declared

and reports `false_type` (which is wrong) if the `OneParamStruct` line is removed.

With `clang++ -std=c++11` (3.8.0) the code compiles but reports `false_type` in both cases.

Is something like that possible at all?

---

**Edit:** Changed the additional type from `void` to `float` to highlight that I want to check if the additional type is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `void_t` trick requires that we give one of the parameters of the primary template a default type of `void`. You had no need for the primary template (`toTypesOf`) to be variadic.

It is more idiomatic for a `bool` type trait to inherit from `false_type` or `true_type` instead of having a nested `type`. There is no need for `TemporaryBindObject` to have a nested `type`.

`TestValidBind` should look something like this:

```
template<template<typename...> class Dest> struct TestValidBind
{
    template<template<typename...> class Dest, typename T, typename = void_t<>> struct toTypesOf
        : std::false_type
    {};
    template<template<typename...> class Dest, template<typename...> class Src, typename... Ts> struct toTypesOf<Dest, Src<Ts...>, void_t<Dest<Ts..., float>>>
        : std::true_type
    {};
};
```

**EDIT:** As you say, this doesn't work with g++, and I don't know why that is. But we can simplify it and see if that helps. We don't actually need the enclosing struct `TestValidBind`. The `toTypesOf` template can be at namespace scope if we transplant the `Dest` parameter into it:

```
template<template<typename...> class Dest, typename T, typename = void_t<>> struct toTypesOf
    : std::false_type
{};
template<template<typename...> class Dest, template<typename...> class Src, typename... Ts> struct toTypesOf<Dest, Src<Ts...>, void_t<Dest<Ts..., float>>>
    : std::true_type
{};
```

This works in g++.

[**DEMO**](http://ideone.com/prVKsV)

We can go further and make it a bit easier to use if you like, by putting everything in a `detail` namespace and wrapping it in an alias template:

```
namespace detail
{
    template<typename... T> using void_t = void;

    template<typename... T> struct TemporaryBindObject {};

    template<template<typename...> class Dest, typename T, typename = void_t<>> struct toTypesOf
        : std::false_type {};
    template<template<typename...> class Dest, template<typename...> class Src, typename... Ts> struct toTypesOf<Dest, Src<Ts...>, void_t<Dest<Ts...>>>
        : std::true_type {};
}

template<template<typename...> class Dest, typename... Ts>
using IsValidBind = typename detail::toTypesOf<Dest, detail::TemporaryBindObject<Ts...>>;

template<template<typename...> class Dest, typename... Ts>
using IsValidBindWithFloat = IsValidBind<Dest, Ts..., float>;

template<template<typename...> class Dest, typename... Ts>
using IsValidBindWithVoid = IsValidBind<Dest, Ts..., void>;

std::cout << "Can bind to TwoParamStruct: " << IsValidBindWithFloat<TwoParamStruct, int>::value << std::endl;
std::cout << "Can bind to OneParamStruct: " << IsValidBindWithFloat<OneParamStruct, int>::value << std::endl;
```

Now we don't need the `using tmp`, and we have a more general solution in which you can easily change the type you want to use as the additional type.

[**DEMO**](http://ideone.com/kFU6lZ)

Comment: Thanks for your valid corrections. Actually, it does not answer my question exactly. I was asking for the opposite which still does not work (probably my example was not well tailored to highlight the point). What I wanted to try was adding an additional type (which I chose to be `void`). I will change it to something else to highlight this point.

Comment: I was a bit too fast with my comment: My example (having a type too many) with your corrections now works with clang but still fails with g++5. Your example works in both compilers.

Comment: I will adjust my question to fit to your answer (because you indeed fixed a stupid mistake) and ask a new question tomorrow. But let me note that I did not change my question with the edit!

Comment: OK, I don't know why g++ doesn't like that. I missed the description "append an additional type"; I was concentrating on the code.

Comment: Now that there is the second answer I cannot change my question... The other answer works with gcc, I still need to check where the difference really is.

Comment: Simple and nice! Do you think I should submit a bug against gcc? (Or maybe first ask the standard experts on SO which compiler is right?)

Comment: I can't say. Maybe asking SO would result in a better [MCVE] to include in the eventual bug report.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I'd do it:

```
using std::void_t; // or write your own
template<class T>struct tag{using type=T;};
template<template<class...>class Z>struct ztag{
  template<class...Ts>using result=Z<Ts...>;
};

namespace details {
  template<class Src, class Target, class=void>
  struct rebind {};
  template<template<class...>class Src, template<class...>class Target, class...Ts>
  struct rebind<Src<Ts...>, ztag<Target>, void_t<Target<Ts...>>>:
    tag<Target<Ts...>>
  {};
}
template<class Src, class zDest>
using rebind = typename details::rebind<Src,zDest>::type;

namespace details {
  template<template<class...>class Z, class, class...Ts>
  struct can_apply : std::false_type {};
  template<template<class...>class Z, class...Ts>
  struct can_apply<Z, void_t<Z<Ts...>>, Ts...> : std::true_type {};
}
template<template<class...>class Z, class...Ts>
using can_apply = typename details::can_apply<Z, void, Ts...>::type;

template<class...>struct types{using type=types;};

namespace details {
  template<class types, class...Us>
  struct append;
  template<class...Ts, class...Us>
  struct append<types<Ts...>, Us...>:
    types<Ts..., Us...>
  {};
}
template<class types, class...Us>
using append = typename details::append<types, Us...>::type;

template<class Src, template<class...>class Dest>
using can_rebind_with_void =
  can_apply< rebind, append< rebind<Src, ztag<types>>, void >, ztag<Dest> >;
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6dfe7e19da2a55ae).

The `ztag` is because metaprogramming is much easier when working only with types.  `ztag` takes a template and turns it into a type.

`zapply` then applies it:

```
namespace details {
  template<class Z, class...Ts>
  struct zapply {};
  template<template<class...>class Z, class...Ts>
  struct zapply<ztag<Z>, Ts...>:
    tag<Z<Ts...>>
  {};
}
template<class Z, class...Ts>
using zapply = typename details::zapply<Z,Ts...>::type;
```

In any case, everything is generic except the one-line solution:

```
template<class Src, template<class...>class Dest>
using can_rebind_with_void =
  can_apply< rebind, append< rebind<Src, ztag<types>>, void >, ztag<Dest> >;
```

Here we ask "can we apply" `rebind< ???, ztag<Dest> >`.  This does a `Dest<???>`.

`???` starts with `Src<???>`, moves its types over to `types<???>`, appends a `void`.  So we get `types<Ts..., void>` from `Src<Ts...>`.

`rebind` takes a type with template args, and a `ztag` of another template, and applies the first arguments template args to the template inside the `ztag`.

`can_apply` asks if the implied template application is legal.  If I was more consistent, `can_apply` would also take a `ztag` as its first argument.

The reason I do all this with `ztag` is because template metaprogramming is smoother is everything is types.